# Getting User Identity on my base Controller constructor

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, .net-4.5

I have a base Controller on my ASP.NET MVC4 website that have a Constructor simple as this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected MyClass Foo { get; set; }
    public BaseController()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated))
        {
            Foo = new MyClass();
        }
    }
}
```

However I cannot access `User` here. It's `null`. But on my inherited **Controllers** it's fine.

Thanks

Comment: Use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User  rather than User

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Controller instantiation will occur before authorisation takes place. Even if your MVC application calls `RenderAction()` several times and you end up creating say, five different controllers, those five controllers will be created before any [OnAuthorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.onauthorization%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) takes place.

The best approach to deal with these situations is to use [Action Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The [Authorize Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is fired early and may well be suited to your situation.

First, let's create an **AuthorizationFilter**.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyClassAuthorizationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData["MyClassInstance"] = new MyClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's update our **Controller**

```
[MyClassAuthorization]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected MyClass Foo
    {
        get { return (MyClass)ViewData["MyClassInstance"]; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case I would [override Controller Initialize method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
   base.Initialize(requestContext);
   // User.Identity is accessible here
}
```