# Identity 2.0 User Identity is null in MVC 5 controller initializer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I have an MVC 5 project using Asp.Net Identity 2.0.  I am also using a generic repository pattern.  As part of the database schema I have fields for various tables which store the user id of the inserting/updating/deleting user.  Therefore I would like to pass the user object, or user id at least to the generic repository to be used when modifying records.

However, as i was unable to access the identity directly in the repository class I am attempting to pass it on repository instantiation.  It looks like this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using My.Models;

namespace My.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class FooController : MasterController
    {
        private IGenericRepositoryAsync<Topic> _repository;

        public FooController()
        {
            //Point A
            _repository = new GenericRepositoryAsync<Foo>(User.Identity);
        }


        public async Foo<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            //POINT B
            //_repository = new GenericRepositoryAsync<Foo>(User.Identity);
            return View(await _repository.GetAllAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

As an authorized user at "Point A" User.Identity is null, at //Point B it is not null but I don't want to have to put the repository initializer in every controller Action.

Your help and feedback is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting User Identity on my base Controller constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236064/getting-user-identity-on-my-base-controller-constructor)

Comment: They are indeed similar, however Freerider's response is current to the MVC 5 + Identity 2.0 implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Web Api solution**

You may create your on Authorize filter class and then add the *userId* into Request properties collection:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
    public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any()) return;

        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);

        Guid userId;

        if (actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated
            && Guid.TryParse(actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId(), out userId))
        {
            actionContext.Request.Properties.Add("userId", actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId());
        }
    }
}
```

Once the class exists, you have to add this filter on Application Startup class (Global.asax web_start, Startup.cs) like this:

```
config.Filters.Add(new MyAuthorizeAttribute());
```

For Owin Startup.cs will be something like this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureOAuth(app);

    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    config.Filters.Add(new MyAuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Then, in your controller you will be able to get the *userId* jus doing:

```
Guid userId = (Guid) ActionContext.Request.Properties["userId"];
```

**MVC Solution**

For MVC use directly on Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

...

User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Or add a filter as in Web Api solution:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    ...
    Guid userId = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.GetUserId();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am having some difficulty getting this to work, errors include  "there is no suitable method to override", something with the async, and "cannot resolve symbol 'RequestContext'".  Note this is an MVC implementation, not WebAPi.

Comment: @John I have edited my answer for MVC. I haven't tested it but should work.

Answer (score -1):

Minor clarication for MVC, `GetUserId` should be called from inside `OnAuthentication()`, the user ID is not available yet in the constructor:

```
protected override void OnAuthentication(System.Web.Mvc.Filters.AuthenticationContext filterContext) {
      Repo = new ReposWrapper();

      try {
         Repo.CurrentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
      } catch (NullReferenceException) {}

      base.OnAuthentication(filterContext);
}
```