# Why does System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User resolve during a controller constructor, but User.Identity does not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, wif

Rowan Freeman's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236064/getting-user-identity-on-my-base-controller-constructor#) describes why `User.Identity` is null during the constructor of a controller. A comment on the same question points out that `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User` does result in the expected value in the same context.

Why is `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User` valid during the controller's constructor even though `User.Identity` is not?

Will using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` during the constructor of a controller potentially result in bugs?

Edit for clarification:

From the linked article, regarding `User.Identity`: "Controller instantiation will occur before authorization takes place. Even if your MVC application calls RenderAction() several times and you end up creating say, five different controllers, those five controllers will be created before any OnAuthorization takes place."

Does the above paragraph not apply to `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`? I am hoping to better understand the nuance between the two that makes them appear to behave differently, to hopefully understand whether `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is acceptable to use outside of an individual action but inside the controller.

Comment: Putting logic into a controller's constructor is generally a bad idea. The constructor is executed for *every* request. A best practice is to never do anything in the constructor except assign dependencies, and then do your heavy lifting in those dependent services. Another alternative is to use [authorization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter(v=vs.118).aspx) or [action filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iactionfilter(v=vs.118).aspx). There are many ways to execute code without clutter in the controller's constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts on this. I am considering the controller constructor to create a data service class instance aware of the currently logged in user's AspNetUserId. This would allow the individual actions in the controller to not need to pass an AspNetUserId into every request. But I don't understand MVC well enough to be sure I am not introducing fragility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will using System.Web.HttpContext.Current during the constructor of a controller potentially result in bugs?

It will introduce an undesirable dependency, which will, for example, prevent you from being able to unit test the controller properly.

You might consider overriding `Controller.Initialize` instead to add your own initializ

Comment: Good thoughts. Thank you. If I understand correctly, overloaded controller constructors (as demonstrated in the [repository pattern](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) should address the dependency concern, as long as the controller doesn't rely on storing the entire class object.