# Access Identity User from base controller constructor in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I tried to access the Identity current User in my abstract base controller constructor to use the link to display user in View if It signed in.

So, I got `User` property is `null`. Everybody advice use filter and return User via ViewData. Example here: ["Why is User (as in User.Identity.Name) null in my abstract base controller?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19236818/5091529)

I tried do somethink like this, but face with the problem: `AuthorizationContext` **has no member** `Controller`!

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class UserAuthorizationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["IdentityUser"] = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
    }
}
```

So, I have two questions:

- Is there any way to send data from Filter to the Controller?
- Maybe there is any other way to get not null User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using an Action Filter as opposed to an Authorisation Filter.  These are processed later in the pipeline, and have access to the user.